# Webpack config not accepting to config mode option

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-hot-middleware

**getting error when trying to add mode option to the webpack config i need to configure {mode:'developement' } to enable hmp by looking at this answer github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-middleware/issues/… **

> WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack
>   has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match
>   the API schema.
>        - configuration has an unknown property 'mode'. These properties are valid:
>          object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?,
>   node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?,
>   recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?,
>   target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
>          For typos: please correct them.
>          For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
>            Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
>            Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
>            plugins: [
>              new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
>                // test: /.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
>                options: {
>                  mode: ...
>                }
>              })
>            ]
>           at webpack (C:\Users\asdf\WebstormProjects\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:19:9)
>           at Object. (
>           at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>           at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>           at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>           at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
>           at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:282:19)
>           at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

```
    /* eslint-disable */
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const commonConfig = require('./webpack.config.common');

module.exports = webpackMerge(
  commonConfig,
  {
    devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
    entry: {
      main: ['babel-polyfill', 'webpack-hot-middleware/client', './app/index.js'],
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname,
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: '[hash].bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.mspcss/,
          use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader?modules=true&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
            'resolve-url-loader',
            'sass-loader?sourceMap'
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader?sourceMap']
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
          BABEL_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
        },
        __DEV__: true,
      }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
      new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        title: 'some- Development',
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.ejs'),
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        favicon: 'favicon.ico',
        inject: 'body'
      }),

    ]
  }
)
/* eslint-enable */
```

Comment: You really need to reformat this to make it more readable for us.

Comment: can you edit this i dont know how to do it

Comment: Please share your webpack configuration

Comment: shared@Helenesh

Comment: i need to configure {mode:'developement' } to enable hmp  by looking at this answer https://github.com/webpack-contrib/webpack-hot-middleware/issues/255#issuecomment-375603384

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What version of webpack are you using? You are probably on version 2 or 3 and the latest version of webpack-dev-server (3.2.1) targets webpack 4. I had the same issue and fixed it by installing webpack-dev-server version 2.11.5

```
npm uninstall webpack-dev-server
npm i -D webpack-dev-server@2.11.5
```

Comment: So seems the solution is to downgrade. Not really a solution.